# Node Js Angular 4 CORS

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Is it safe to allow CORS in NodeJS by allowing through ExpressJs?

If " No " - How would I solve when my angularJs running on port - 4200 and NodeJS running on port - 3000 with error - "No-Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

```js
app.use((request,response,next) => {
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();    
})
```

Comment: You can specify origins..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897801/enable-access-control-allow-origin-for-multiple-domains-in-nodejs this will do the trick

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-proxy

Comment: safe from what?

Comment: Safe - In general organisations doesn't allow cors as they might hacked into the server and steal data which I want to prevent from happening.@kevin B