# Allowing CORS only for my domain?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cors, preflight

I have an `AngularJs` website and when I am trying to post data then when I am opening my website without using `www` then I am getting

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Otherwise, I am not getting any error.

I tried to search and found that I should implement `CORS` on my backend which is in `NodeJs` but can anyone please tell me how can I only implement `CORS` **Headers** such that for both `www` and without, it would work but for any other domain trying to access my API must result in **preflight error**.

I am trying to do this because I read here [which-security-risks-do-cors-imply](https://mobilejazz.com/blog/which-security-risks-do-cors-imply/) that allowing all domains can increase security overhead for my website which I do not want.

Thanks.

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/32481816/5621827

Comment: header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*.domain.com")

Comment: why not redirect any `www` requests to non `www`? Most people don't use `www` any more

Comment: @charlietfl can you please tell me how can I do that ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not something you can tweak just in your client-side code. In order for cross-origin requests to work, you need to set an **http response header**: it's the server, who serves the resource, who will need the change, not the client side code from `angularJs`.

I believe that you should update your question stating what your server side language is and how are you handling http requests in the server side. As far as I know, just adding a header like:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://client.domain.com
In your responses will do the trick. Where `client.domain.com` is the domain of your client, angularJs application.

Comment: It's in Nodejs.

Comment: expressJs I guess?