# Get Token in Firebase Functions When Requesting With An Authorization Bearer

Tags: node.js, firebase, http-headers, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently using Firebase Functions `v1.0.3` and Firebase Admin `v5.12.1`. It seems to be working fine with the `express` NodeJS library.

**Issue**

However, when I tried to secure the request by sending an Authorization header:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

It did not show any logs of my tokens. I couldn't see any words that matches `Bearer` or `Authorization Bearer` (whatsoever) when I used `console.log(request)` inside my Firebase Functions `index.js` file to get the `token`.

All I get was the following from `req.headers` when I use `console.log`:

```
{ 'content-length': '0',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  referer: 'http://localhost:5000/admin/',
  accept: '*/*',
  'access-control-request-headers': 'authorization,content-type',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36',
  origin: 'http://localhost:5000',
  'access-control-request-method': 'GET',
  connection: 'close',
  host: 'localhost:5001' 
}
```

**Documentation Sources**

I've read a documentation about [Firebase Functions Samples: Authorized HTTPS Endpoint](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint) sample codes, and some of it seems outdated.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken()
```

For instance is now:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
```

**Other Libaries**

I've tried to install libraries such as `express-authorization-bearer` and `express-bearer-token`, and I could still not catch the `idToken`.

I'm wondering if this is a NodeJS issue or a Firebase Functions issue. I'm currently using NodeJS `v6.11.4`

**Question**

How do I catch the token inside Firebase Functions using Express or any method using NodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Authorization bearer worked. Here are the results when I `console.log(req.headers)`:

```
{ 'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  referer: 'http://localhost:5000/admin/',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36',
  origin: 'http://localhost:5000',
  authorization: 'Bearer something',
  connection: 'close',
  host: 'localhost:5001' }
```

The `token` is `something` in this case

**Important notes:**

- The `req.headers.authorization` does not work with [Assigning Multiple Origins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897801/enable-access-control-allow-origin-for-multiple-domains-in-nodejs), because it gives the error `Cannot set headers after they are sent`, but it should work easily by allowing any origin and with `cors` as a middleware:

  `var cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
  app.use(cors);`

  The `req.headers.authorization` is already securing it, anyway.
- `req.headers.authorization` can not be assigned to a parameter, otherwise it will become `undefined`
- Using the same documentation from [Authorized HTTPS Endpoints](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint), it should completely work only if `cors`, `cookies` with `cookie-parser` plugin, and `req.headers.authorization` are completely enabled and sent to the `firebase-functions` endpoint.