# req.headers.origin always undefined, how to allow multiple domains for ALLOW-FROM

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to allow `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (CORS) and `ALLOW-FROM` (iframe) for multiple addresses. I've looked around and found this:

[Enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin for multiple domains in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897801/enable-access-control-allow-origin-for-multiple-domains-in-nodejs)

and several others which say to do something like this:

```
const allowedOrigins = ["https://example1.com", "https://example2.com"];

if (allowedOrigins.includes(req.headers.origin)) {
    res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin);
    res.set("X-Frame-Options", `ALLOW-FROM ${req.headers.origin}`);
}
```

The problem is that `req.headers.origin` is always *undefined*, in development and production server. When I look in the Network tab of the Web Inspector, there is never a request header named *origin*, only *host* or sometimes *referer*.

So I tried the following:

```
const origin = `${req.protocol}://${req.headers.host}`;
res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
```

This is working good, but it can't be used for the `X-Frame-Options` header, because *host* is the address on which the web resides, not the address of the iframe parent. I need `ALLOW-FROM https://example1.com`, not `ALLOW-FROM https://myapp.com`. Can you help me with it please?

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping, this is what you are looking for:

```
Configuring CORS w/ Dynamic Origin
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var whitelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
var corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
}

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for a whitelisted domain.'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```

Comment: Hi, I need to set X-Frame-Options for multiple domains, so they can embed my site in an iframe. Does `cors` also set this header? It seems to have a different purporse (CORS handling).

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but how does that help me? It just seems like a more complicated way of writing `res.set("X-Frame-Options", "Deny");`