# Allowed hosts for serverMiddleware

Tags: express, nuxt.js, servermiddleware, allowed-origin

I have built a NUXT app, and I've added to it a serverMiddleware for handling some REST endpoints and connecting to my database.

```js
serverMiddleware: [
  { path: "/api", handler: "~/api/index.js" },
],
```

So my question is: How to restrict accessing to /api endpoints from only few hosts ? (like having a list of ALLOWED_ORIGINS)

Comment: Your question is mainly focused on Express itself per-se, nothing specific to Nuxt. So, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32481816/8816585) should be a good starting regarding the configuration of such behavior. The bigger image is to check the origin, if it's coming from an allowed place and denying/allowing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin in header resolves my question.

Comment: Perfect, feel free to mark my question as accepted if it helped you somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the header solved the issue as explained more in-depth on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32481816/8816585

Since at the end, this part of Nuxt is a regular Express app.